# Can't replace submit button with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do my first tests usign JQuery and it seems to be more difficult than what I expected.
I have a simple form calling some long operations. What I want is to display a progress bar during the loading. What I try to do in the following code is to replace the submit button with a progress bar when the user submits the form. The next page taking time to load, he will see a nice animation making him wait.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myCuteLittleForm"><input type="submit" id="submit"/></form> 
    <br />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCuteLittleForm').submit(function() {
          $("#submit").replaceWith('<progress value="" max="">Import en cours.</progress>');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, to my great distress, it doesn't work. Am I just doing bad jquery or is there a fundamental incomprehension ?

Comment: The progress bar needs to have a value between 1 - 100. But you need to set that yourself, it doesn't work automatically. So you need a script to do that for you.

Comment: It works without values, I already tried.

Comment: It has a nice animation, but it doesn't fill the bar. I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: Na, filling the bar will be done a next time :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in other script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myCuteLittleForm').submit(function() {
          $("#submit").replaceWith('<progress value="" max="">Import en cours.</progress>');
      });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: He was too fast, I have to wait at least 10 minutes.